# Sinch IOS instant message push notification with sound and badge

Tags: ios, push-notification, sinch

For Sinch iOS instant message, how could I configure the push notification with sound and badge?

Currently it only display an alert without sound and badge. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using managed push or pushing your self?

Comment: @cjensen I used the managed push. I set up all the requirement followed the document in Sinch Instant Message, Local and Remote Push Notification chapter.  The URL: https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/ios/#localandremotepushnotifications

Comment: Sorry, its two features missing from our managed push, they are in the works

Comment: @cjensen OK, hope you can release this feature soon. I love Sinch a lot, and this seems like the only shortcoming of current Sinch instant message services.

Comment: just tidying up, can you please mark below as answered?

Comment: @cjensen is the missing features of push are added? Actually i am implementing Instant Messaging and the push Banner is SIN_INCOMING_IM, how i can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently not supported on managed push

Comment: Is this still currently not supported?